Cloud Run deployment failed - "Revision with different configuration already exists"?
I'm wanted to deploy a new version of my Go app to Cloud Run, but am getting the following error:
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) ALREADY_EXISTS: Revision named 'go-app-00014-yev' with different configuration already exists.

I directly deploy using gcloud run deploy from the terminal, without using any YAML configuration files. Haven't had this issue before... Could it be because I've updated some revision configurations through the Google Cloud Console (settings and env vars)? I did that a few revisions ago, but the error only just started appearing.

It seems like your template has a set revision name now. You can set --revision-suffix="" to clear the configured name and go back to autogenerating new names for each deploy.

I have no idea how that would have happened, but thanks, your solution worked!
